# Choosing right deployment model for web app / api (IaaS, PaaS?)

Tags: cloud

We have a project in plan which will use the following technologies:

1) asp.net mvc + angular for front end

2) asp.net web api RESTful service

3) windows services in background for different purposes

4) message queues/brokers for exchanging messages between 2) and 3)

5) MS SQL database

6) Redis or similar cache

We expect significant traffic down the road (tens of thousands requests / sec in peek times) and anticipate need for scaling out / load balancing.

As we have no experience with cloud PaaS so far (always used on-premise hosting or for example rackspace could servers IaaS) i would like to get some recommendations about what is the most usual / common way to go with cloud hosting in such scenario?

My first thought is to go with IaaS VMs as our stuff is used to it. On the other hand, i would not like to miss PaaS benefits if there are some for our case.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With all due respect, this question will most likely be closed as it is asking for recommendations and is quite broad. If I were you, I would simply start by using IaaS VMs so that I can get a feel of Azure and then gradually start moving services into PaaS (there are very many services to choose from) as I get more understanding of the platform.

Comment: thank you for your input. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Definitly look at some of the PaaS offerings at least for the persistence layer. Azure (assumed if using .NET MVC) already provides Redis as a Service, MSSQL as a service, etc. No need to worry about backups, nodes going down, managing a redis cluster, etc.

It only takes a few seconds to provision a new Db and you can maintain the same Redis client libs, JDBC connections, etc. Same goes for using Azure Event Hub or Storage Queues. Db stuff is always hard to get right initially and support it.

For the web app stuff, you can try the IaaS route, especially if you're already familiar with it, but still be pointing to managed Db hosts urls. Much of the Web App PaaS is pretty quick to pick up if you're already used to IaaS in the cloud. Azure just provides some additional benefits when it comes to auto scaling, deployment, etc. But you are still working with the same old C# code.